# Noun for particles that are quantumly entangled

Tags: terminology, quantum-entanglement

What will we call particles that are in a "quantum entanglement" kind of relationship?
not looking for examples (like thingamatrons can participate theoretically in quantum entanglement); rather the noun part / nomenclature
like the

particles that exhibit quantum entanglement are called __________ mirrors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Particles that exhibit quantum entanglement are called ***entangled*** -- that is, "entangled particles".  Being entangled is a property, and thus, it is described by an adjective.

Comment: they *are* entangled. But will they have a name? like how a particle with positive charge is called proton

Comment: See my edit.  --- And a particle with positive charge is not necessarily a proton.

Comment: hmm in the context of my question, what you are saying makes sense. i was trying to find a word which can then be used in this question (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/504795/whats-a-word-for-a-doppelgänger-only-in-ones-shlemazlut) and all...but thats not the realm of physics stackexchange

Comment: yeah i knew "not necessarily a proton" thing would come up here lol, but it was as an example...

Comment: @harshvchawla A word which only denotes an example - i.e. a specific instance - is not a word for the general case.

Comment: yups @norbert, thats why when i posted my comment, i was thinking "maybe i should have rephrased it as "proton is the name of a particle with a positive charge" (I should learn to be precise over being quick sometimes :p). thanks though for your followup

Comment: @harshvchawla Protons can also be entangled.  So would "proton" be ok for you?

Comment: can all entangled particles be called "proton"? (when you reach the finish line, you need to stop running...)

Comment: @harshvchawla Can all positively charged particles be called "proton"?